# C# Fill Data Grid View after using input list

Tags: c#, sql, list

I really need your expert help :).  Expanding on what I have learnt from querying data sets using adapters and filling a Grid View. I need some help on the following task.

I have a SQL Server Database which I am querying using C#. I already have solid working solutions of by a date range, a specific value. However, the business user would like to search by a list of values they provide as input into a form.

Similar to the below:
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mindate", textBox1.Text);

The input will be taken from a text box or similar form based element. There should be no defined limit to the number of values e.g. I don't want to prevent the user from inputting 100 values for example.

By way of example.
User input: doc1.num1.value;doc2.num1.value;doc3.num1.value etc
Note: The document number field may contain a full stop. However, each value will be terminated by a ';'

In the above example, we would run the following query: select employee_id, docNumbers from tableName where docNumbers in (inputlist)

And the output would be:
Record 1: 1, doc1.num1.value
Record 2: 2, doc2.num1.value
Record 3: 3, doc3.num1.value

Thanks in advance guys and gals.

Comment: please post some code of what you have already tried

Comment: your question is more likely answered before.
Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is using an IN clause when doing your query.

Comment: Thanks again for the link. This option looks like a nice solution to what I want to achieve and better optimized if the user entered a long list: http://stackoverflow.com/a/337907/1510762. I will give that a try :)

Comment: Good to heard that. Happy coding. =]

Comment: Chinz if I had enough rep I would increment for you. Currently working on this now and will set to solved once I cracked it :)